# Cannot install youtube v3 nuget package

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to install youtube api v3 in UWP but I got the error **System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Process on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).**

Comment: Please provide us with more information.

Which version of VS/NuGet are you using?

What is the target framework of your UWP project?

Which version of the youtube api v3 are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide us with the information I mentioned in the comment.

I had no problem installing it for example with the following:

Google.Apis.Youtube.v3 1.25.0.760 - on a UWP proj with TFM versions:

Target Version: Win 10 Creators Update, Build 15063

Min Version: Win 10 November Update, Build 10586